# How to add a custom footer to pdfs created by Liferay DocumentConversionUtil (and open office)

Tags: pdf, liferay, openoffice.org, document-conversion

I am trying to add a custom footer to pdfs created from docx files on my liferay6.2 installation. 
Specifically I have linked up open office, and I am successfully converting the documents from docx to pdf to embed them in my portal, but I want to add a 'pdf created on ' message as a footer.

I am open to doing this through liferay/java or through a setting in open office, but I can't find a way to do either at this time.

Thanks,
Joe

Answer (score 0):

You will need to implement your own `OpenOfficeDocumentConverter`. The current implementation does this:

```
XComponent document = loadDocument(inputUrl, loadProperties);
refreshDocument(document);
storeDocument(document, outputUrl, storeProperties);
```

You could overwrite `refreshDocument` and do what you would like to do with the document (check the [UNO API](http://www.openoffice.org/api/docs/java/ref/overview-summary.html) to find out how to change the document to add the footer).

Unfortunately you can't inject your converter with the spring configuration or `portal.properties`. Either you create an ext-plugin and replace the whole `OpenOfficeDocumentConverter` with your own implementation. Or you set `DocumentConversionUtil._documentConverter` using reflection to your extension.